# Comparing 朝 vs. 向 vs. 往

Tags: difference

In talking about physical/geographical directions, I'm pretty comfortable using 朝 and 向 and 往 for the meaning of "to" or "toward". But I would be hard put to describe to a Chinese language learner any differences in usage or meaning among these three words. Are there any important differences?

Comment: This [link](http://www.easymandarin.net/html/SUPPLEMENTARY-MATERIALS/200808/31-11.html) contains a good description of the similarities and differences of the three words.

Comment: Why is that a comment rather than an answer?

Answer (score 5):

See the [Chinese Grammar Wiki](http://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Comparing_%22chao%22_%22xiang%22_and_%22wang%22). The explanation is quite extensive with many examples.

Some relevant parts:

> 向 and 往 can be placed after the verb, however it has to be used with
>   an appropriate verb, Often used verbs are 开, 飞, 发, 运, 送, 寄, 带, 驶 etc.
>   As you can see, this are words that at least imply some sort of
>   motion. In addition, compared to 向, 往 is used more often with those
>   verbs, because 往 expresses the destination while 向 merely expresses a
>   direction, 朝 cannot be used this way.
>
> When the action that takes place is specified to a specific target,
>   use 向 or 朝. 往 cannot be used this way. Also, when the verb is a
>   concrete action, the use of 向 and 朝 are the same, and they can be
>   interchanged.
>
> When the verb has an abstract meaning, you can only use 向, and you
>   cannot use 朝.